# mysql2 - undefined method `add_foreign_key_constraint'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I run rake `db:migrate` under my database and I get this error:

```
undefined method `add_foreign_key_constraint'
```

I searched for similar issues and tried to use the foreigner gem, but I still get this same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not support creation of FK contraints by default.

You are probably trying to use [Rein](https://github.com/nullobject/rein) gem, which has the `add_foreign_key_constraint` syntax.

Execute `gem install rein` or add `gem 'rein'` in your Gemfile.